# PHP url parameters incorrect

Tags: php, url

must be a silly question for experts, but am getting a wrong output for what seems to my inexperienced eyes a correct code:

```
"www.xxxxxx.com/hdjhs/index.php?id={$id}&email={$email}";
```

it is coming out as:

```
www.xxxxxx.com/hdjhs/index.php?rid={$rid}&email=xxxx@gmail.com
```

i've checked other links but they seem to focus mainly on hardcoded multiple parameters and not dynamic ones. Am sorry if repeated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to give more details about your problem and a piece of code that is producing the incorrect ouput.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer unless you provide some more information and/or some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more code context, but if `$rid` is a typo, and there is no variable named `$rid`, then you will get that output.

Comment: In that case, ensure that $rid is set correctly before outputting that line. It is possible that you've messed something else up and $rid hasn't been set.

Comment: `echo "{$undefinedvar}"` will just echo a blank. Most likely $rid is being mis-assigned elsewhere in the code, something like `$rid = '{$id}';`